# Usb gprs not detected on boot

Tags: usb, boot

Good morning!

I have a Gprs USB module which used to work just fine. Now on boot, the device is not detected. However, when the OS is booted, if I unplug and re-plug in the device, it is detected and works just fine.

What do you guys think? Why do you think the module is not detected anymore on boot time as it used to be?

What can I check?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should check is `dmesg`.

Right after you plug your GPS in a booted system, type `dmesg` on the console and take note of the last 10 lines or so. They should mention the steps your system took when the device was plugged, like loading the driver.

Then, reboot with the GPS plugged in, and check `dmesg` again. Try to find the lines you have seen the first time. There will most likely be messages in the output describing what went wrong.

Of course, the usual advice for situations where something used to work but doesn't work anymore is to roll back the latest changes you have done to your system. If you make backups, all it takes is to restore one.